# Making search in C# but it doesn't work in text searching

Tags: c#, sql

I am faced with a problem that I searched  in google but I don't find my answer. I want to make search in windows form in C# but it working just in numeric value and my project is in Persian so I need to search by nvarchar value, so it doesn't work. Please help me.

Here is my code: it messages this (Incorrect syntax near '=')

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter( @"SELECT Dmokalafiat, Dihteyat FROM Armyservices where Ename = "+ txtsearch.Text,db.con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Textbox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Dmokalafiat"].ToString();
    Textbox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Dihteyat"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because of SQL Injection attacks. you can make it like this sample code:

```
 using(var con = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("select Dmokalafiat, Dihteyat  from Armyservices where Ename = @Ename ", con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ename ", txtsearch.Text);
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    var dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
      if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
        Textbox1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Dmokalafiat"].ToString();
        Textbox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Dihteyat"].ToString();
      }
    }
```

Comment: That is  like to don't execute the query it dose Not give any message. And it also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your example;

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter( @"SELECT Dmokalafiat, Dihteyat FROM Armyservices where Ename = "+ txtsearch.Text,db.con);
```

Should at least be

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter( @"SELECT Dmokalafiat, Dihteyat FROM Armyservices where Ename = '"+ txtsearch.Text + "'",db.con);
```

However this is not really good practise and you should use named parameters instead of concatenated values - but thats a different question.

Comment: Quotes are unnecessary at the begining and ending of the line.

Comment: Thanks @Berkay - I've altered now.